# iPhone 4 - Camera flash stays lit even when the phone is off

Tags: iphone

I was given an iphone 4 to fix. I've replaced screens before, but this guy tried to do it himself but he couldn't do it. When I got the phone, the flash lit up. It wasn't a full "flash" like you get from some flashlight applications, it was just dimmly lit.

I took apart the phone. Successfully put it back together, and the little light from the flash was still there. Even when the phone is powered off, it stays on. I can go into the camera app now, and if I take a picture, it FLASHES, but then it stays dimmly lit. Any ideas at all? Hardware problem? Is there anyway to reset this?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a hardware problem. It comes from the flash not being properly connected or the connectors on the board being damaged. Normally reseating the connection fixes the issue. He was probably a little heavy handed when he put the phone back together or the board has suffered ESD damage.

As well as this being annoying, it will drain the battery.